# Problem to install or remove any software"lvm2-lvmetad.service"

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I am trying to install or remove any software but I am facing the error below:

```
Failed to restart lvm2-lvmetad.service: Unit lvm2-lvmetad.socket is masked.
invoke-rc.d: initscript lvm2-lvmetad, action "restart" failed.
● lvm2-lvmetad.service - LVM2 metadata daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lvm2-lvmetad.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-05-16 06:40:37 WAT; 1h 54min ago
     Docs: man:lvmetad(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lvm2-lvmetad.service

May 16 06:40:37 raikone-X555UB systemd[1]: Starting LSB: LVM2 metadata daemon...
May 16 06:40:37 raikone-X555UB systemd[1]: Started LSB: LVM2 metadata daemon.
dpkg: error processing package lvm2 (--configure):
 installed lvm2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lvm2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to follow some tutorials here but didn't work for me.

Comment: Now I tried:    apt-get -f install

dpkg --configure -a
                
apt-get update
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get check

apt-get -m update

apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 14):

I've resolved this problem with:

```
sudo apt-get purge lvm2
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install lvm2
```

reboot the system, and new kernel should be installed. Furthermore, this [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/q/1049727/396822) helped me.

Answer (score 6):

If `systemctl status lvm2-lvmetad` returns `Loaded: masked (/dev/null)` you should unmask and enable it with

```
sudo systemctl unmask  lvm2-lvmetad && sudo systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad
```

The command `systemctl status lvm2-lvmetad.socket` should return status confirming success.

If this approach doesn't work for you, you may have better luck with the purge/reinstall approach described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061188/225694) I would recommend having a [good backup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) though.

Source:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307058/67643

Comment: @HelderJúnior I'm glad this solution worked for you. The way we say thank you here is by accepting/upvoting answers that were the most helpful to us. As I recall this is mentioned in [the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this was a much better solution than purging and reinstalling lvm2! I had to `unmask` a few other things too in my particular case, but once I had the idea down it was just iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. In my case I ran the following commands to solve it:

```
sudo /bin/rm -rf /etc/lvm/  
sudo rm -rf /etc/lvm/backup/
sudo apt purge lvm2
sudo updatdb
sudo locate lvm2
sudo rm /var/crash/lvm2.0.crash
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/lvm2-*
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/lvm2-*
sudo apt install lvm2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```